# Google Map API click event does not work in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I downloaded Google map API control sample project from [here](http://shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html) and used this control and code feature in my project, but click event raised an error and is not working in Mozilla Firefox. The text of this error is

```
TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored"
```

that I see in Firebug console panel.
Page and click events work properly in IE browser.
Can any one help to resolve this problem, please?

A page showing the error is here: http://shabdar.somee.com/MapClickEvent.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Error message

```
TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored
```

is reported for line

```
while (caller.arguments.callee.caller && --recursionLimit) {
```

for one of included script which uses `use strict;` mode.

From [MDN Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode):

*Third, arguments.callee is no longer supported. In normal code arguments.callee refers to the enclosing function. This use case is weak: simply name the enclosing function! Moreover, arguments.callee substantially hinders optimizations like inlining functions, because it must be made possible to provide a reference to the un-inlined function if arguments.callee is accessed. arguments.callee for strict mode functions is a non-deletable property which throws when set or retrieved:...*

I don't know if for example Chrome is less strict with checking or that script was not called at all.

**Update:** Fix could be to change map click event listener to:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lblPushpin1').innerHTML = event.latLng.lat() + ':' + event.latLng.lng();
    });
```

Comment: However, how can I solve this problem with Firefox. I desperately need to have this matter resolved., But I do not have access to the file that the error is reported.
What are your suggestions for a quick fix to this problem?